# How can I change maximum windows size?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do program in C# that allows the user to change the maximum size of windows when he click maximize button. Program will help user to always see part of Desktop.

Here is a picture that explains what I need.

[image: maxmized window]

I want the user to specify margins values of any side[left, top, right, bottom].

Thanks everyone...

Comment: Set the MaximumSize property.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to do that in my application. I want to apply that on all windows programs

Comment: @RomCoo: It's slightly possible, using APIs like DeskBands.

Comment: @SLaks: Could You help me more?